# Why is Singular Value Decomposition [Orth][Diag][Orth]? Why not just [Orth][Diag]

Tags: linear-algebra

Seems like you can take any vector and rotate it and then stretch it...why the need to make a second rotation?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=UD$$

where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

This imply that the columns are orthogonal to each other which is not true.

Comment: Yeah this makes a lot of sense. Thanks! Is it at least true that the action of a matrix on a _single vector_ is equivalent to the action of [Orth][Diag] on the vector? (Obviously, this [Orth][Diag] action shouldn't be the same in general for all other vectors, as you have shown)

Comment: I believe this is true. That is given $x$, we can find particular $D$ and $U$ which depends on $x$ satisfying $Ax=UDx$. $U^TAx=Dx$, if $Ax=0$, we let $D=0$. Suppose not, use householder and permutation to arrange it such that it becomes an element of the standard unit basis. Let entries of $D$ to be all $0$ besides $1$ that corresponds to the standard unit basis.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of taking [orth][diag] would simply result in the multiplication of the column of [orth] by the corresponding diagonal entries of [diag].

A $2 \times 2$ example:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a\lambda_1 & c\lambda_2 \\ b\lambda_1 & d\lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$$